# Redirect to Laravel framework page

Tags: php, laravel, http-headers, cgi

I need to redirect from a CGI to a page of the same server created in Laravel. When I use the path from a browser it presents itself without problems, but when using the CGI, Laravel presents an error to me.

[https://myserver:8080/bitacora/index.php/devices](http://about:blank)

Error when using `Location: /bitacora/index.php/devices` header from a CGI

The only difference I see in PHP is that it does not use QUERY_STRING, but the "arguments" are delivered by the PHP_SELF variable.

Any ideas on how to act correctly? I remember that some frameworks redirect to a variable, such as **module** or **action**. Something similar in Laravel?

[image: Failed to use Location via CGI]

Comment: have you tried full URL when `Location: /bitacora/index.php/devices` like `Location: https://myserver:8080/bitacora/index.php/devices`

Comment: Perfect! I replace with `echo "Location: http://${HTTP_HOST}${MVTO}"` and work fine. Thanks for that. Please add the answer to check it.

Comment: PS: mod_rewrite switch to https

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer as you said. That might help other viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full URL 
not just 
`Location: /bitacora/index.php/devices`

But replace this with following
`Location: http://myserver:8080/bitacora/index.php/devices`.